# Число в дату Excel

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Во второй строчке представлены даты в виде числа (текста), необходимо создать дату с этим числом. Например: D5 = 5, а надо создать из него дату вида 5.09.2017.

Знаю, тип поля можно перевести в дату, но тогда дата выглядит так 5.01.1900.

Подскажите как массово создать дату для всей 2 строки, с переносом имеющегося числа в день?

[Ссылка на пример таблицы](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1veH0-0K6A2ai72Cpl1HUrt87qR2XHUda/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: 1 -> 1.09.2017;    
5 -> 5.09.2017;    
6 -> 6.09.2017;     
7 -> 7.09.2017;    
7 -> 7.09.2017;

Comment: Год и месяц получается я сама задаю, а день месяца переносится из поля

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно, почему для создания даты берем значение строки 5 (в примере там нет данных). А в четвертой строке есть буквы "Н", с которыми дату не создать...

Для большей гибкости формулы год и месяц задать в отдельных ячейках:

```
=ЕСЛИ(C5="";;ДАТА($B$2;$B$1;C5))
```

где в *B1* - месяц, *B2* - год

А можно интереснее.

В *С1* вместо названия месяца вписать дату первого числа нужного месяца (*01.01.2019*). Выбрать формат ячейки (`[$-419]mmmm;@` - *сентябрь* , `[$-F419]yyyy, mmmm;@` - *сентябрь, 2019*...). И все, не нужны доп. ячейки:

```
=ЕСЛИ(C5="";;ДАТА(ГОД($C$1);МЕСЯЦ($C$1);C5))
```

При отсутствии значения в ячейку можно ставить пустой текст (`ЕСЛИ(C5="";"";...`). Но это нежелательно, т.к. наличие текстовых значений среди дат может помешать при дальнейших вычислениях.

Сейчас в ячейку записывается ноль (можно и так - `ЕСЛИ(C5="";0;...`). Нули (или *00.01.1900* при формате даты) мешают восприятию. Но нулевые значения можно скрыть:

закладка `Файл-Параметры-Дополнительно-Показать параметры для листа` (выбрать лист), снять галку `показывать нули в ячейках`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, ошиблась, в данном примере дата берется из строки 2

Answer (score 0):

Не понятно откуда брать год (в 19-ом году в примере год 2017).

Если можно подставить текущий год и название месяца написано без опечаток, то хорошо работает

```
=ДАТАЗНАЧ(C2 & " " & $C$1)
=DATEVALUE(C2 & " " & $C$1)
```